# In vb.net is there a way to hash strings into long

Tags: file-io, hash

Basically we want to preserve memories. It's for tasks like making unique of large files.

Comment: There are infinite ways to hash a string into a long.  What have you tried?  What problems are you having?  Have you tried googling "vb.net <hashing algo here>"?

Comment: yea, what? md5 hash would has a string into a byte ().

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ensure that a file has unique line in vb.net if the size of the file is very big](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004974/how-to-ensure-that-a-file-has-unique-line-in-vb-net-if-the-size-of-the-file-is-v)

Comment: You can convert an array of bytes into a long.  However, most hashing algorithms create a hash too large to fit in a single long.  What is wrong with an array of bytes?

Comment: Basically, I can tolerate that several different strings are hashed into the same long. The file is large, so I want to minimize memory usage as much as possible.

Comment: A long is 64 bits in VB.net, if I remember correctly.  An md5 hash is 128 bits.  That's not much of a difference in the big scheme of things.  I'm sure there's some hashing algo out that that produces a hash <= 64 bits.

Comment: Actually GetHashCode will convert that to integer, which is 32 bit. Good enough. I thought md5 is long string?

Comment: Okay, say I use md5, which is 128 bit. How to compare that the has is already around?

Comment: Ah I get it. Hmm.. gethashcode will give you an integer hash. While that's fine a normal long has would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object.GetHashCode

That's it. Integer is good enough.